# iOS app crashing for apple review team and can't replicate

Tags: objective-c, ios

My app is crashing for the apple review team but I can't replicate the issue.  They sent me the crash log.

```
Incident Identifier: 
CrashReporter Key:   d91f018f5afc31f948a80025c7a09bb112a3caf4
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         
Path:            
Identifier:      
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-06-12 09:27:55.479 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3766b88f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35370259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3766ea9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 175
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3766d915 ___forwarding___ + 301
4   CoreFoundation                  0x375c8650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
5   Sportal_TDF                     0x00031515 -[MenuViewController showStageList:] (MenuViewController.m:62)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x375ca1fb -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 43
7   Sportal_TDF                     0x00005d93 -[DataViewControllerBase retrieveCachedJson:json:cacheAction:] (DataViewControllerBase.m:468)
8   Sportal_TDF                     0x00005e57 -[DataViewControllerBase callWebService:json:cacheAction:successAction:] (DataViewControllerBase.m:480)
9   Sportal_TDF                     0x000314f9 -[MenuViewController loadUpcomingStage] (MenuViewController.m:57)
10  Sportal_TDF                     0x000317b9 -[MenuViewController viewWillAppear:] (MenuViewController.m:142)
11  UIKit                           0x31381b95 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 145
12  UIKit                           0x31525ad1 __52-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:]_block_invoke_0 + 137
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3765f631 __NSArrayEnumerate + 365
14  CoreFoundation                  0x375c4ed5 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 65
15  UIKit                           0x31381c39 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 309
16  UIKit                           0x31381a49 -[UIViewController viewWillMoveToWindow:] + 233
17  UIKit                           0x31342b05 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 529
18  UIKit                           0x313424ab -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 303
19  UIKit                           0x31342377 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 31
20  UIKit                           0x31377555 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 289
21  UIKit                           0x31369e87 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 295
22  UIKit                           0x313da7d5 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 25
23  Sportal_TDF                     0x000030b3 -[Sportal_TDFAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (Sportal_TDFAppDelegate.m:107)
24  UIKit                           0x31377cab -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1183
25  UIKit                           0x313717dd -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 409
26  UIKit                           0x3133fac3 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1011
27  UIKit                           0x3133f567 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 55
28  UIKit                           0x3133ef3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5827
29  GraphicsServices                0x33d8122b PurpleEventCallback + 883
30  CoreFoundation                  0x3763f523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 39
31  CoreFoundation                  0x3763f4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 141
32  CoreFoundation                  0x3763e313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
33  CoreFoundation                  0x375c14a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
34  CoreFoundation                  0x375c136d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
35  UIKit                           0x3137086b -[UIApplication _run] + 551
36  UIKit                           0x3136dcd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
37                      0x00002a07 main (main.m:16)
38                      0x000029a0 0x1000 + 6560
```

It is crashing on line

```
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
```

How can I debug when I can't replicate the issue? Has anyone experienced this issue.  My app was working fine in previous versions but this time it is crashing in 5.1.1.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What does `[MenuViewController showStageList:]` contain on line 62!?

Obviously you are calling a method, that's non existent: `[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]`.

Comment: Thanks yes this pointed me in the right direction.  The problem related to JSON.h in the facebook implementation.  The JSON.m file wasn't present but the app wasn't crashing for us for some reason? We assumed the implementation was in the .a file.  Can anyone explain why it wasn't crashing for me but was crashing for the Apple review team.